# Setting both read() and send() timeouts for the same C socket on linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, timeout

I managed to set a `read` timeout for a C socket with:

```
struct timeval tv_read;
tv_read.tv_sec = 2;
tv_read.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(my_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv_read, sizeof tv_read);
```

Now, I want to make this same socket timeouts for `send` operations. I have found in [setsockopt](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt) that the proper way to set a timeout for `send` is quite similar, just replacing `SO_RCVTIMEO` by `SO_SNDTIMEO`:

```
struct timeval tv_write;
tv_write.tv_sec = 4;
tv_write.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(my_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (const char*)&tv_write, sizeof tv_write);
```

My question is if does a successive call of `setsockopt` overrides the previous one? Or should I actually call twice being one with `SO_RCVTIMEO` and other with `SO_SNDTIMEO` as shown above?

Comment: It's quite common to call setsockopt multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setsockopt()` sets 1 specific option at a time.  It is perfectly fine to set multiple options individually.